# How different were the conditions for generals in the Mongol Invasions of Korea?

Tags: mongol-empire

[This question](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskHistorians/comments/4sx7yt/how_differently_if_at_all_did_genghis_khan_eat/) asks about the different conditions for the Mongol leaders versus the average Mongol, while on campaign. During the [Mongol invasion of Korea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mongol_invasions_of_Korea) (circa 1231-1270), how much better were the generals on both sides treated then their soldiers?

Comment: Do you mean the 20th century Korean war or something else?

Comment: Mongol generals or Korean generals?

Comment: Korean. Non-20th century.

Comment: I do not understand the question, what are you looking at when you say **"conditions"** -- titles, size of army, food, etc? As it stands, this question too broad for me, and I don't feel like writing a book-sized answer. If it's just focused on food, then No, in general, when campaigning (fighting), there is no '*special treatment*' other than respecting the commanders (not family).

Comment: I don't mean food specifically. I am more generally asking about food, living spaces, and health.